# Spring Boot (v2.3.1): Spring Batch Partition w/JdbcPagingItemReader using SimplePartitioner Helper Class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I would like to gain some clarity on exactly how a Partitioner is supposed to work. I implemented the `SimplePartitioner` (helper class provided by Spring) into a `JdbcPagingItemReader`, it working for the most part but the issue is that I see duplicate data/records come through the `ItemWriter`. First I thought there was an issue with my query returning dupes, that is not the case. Right off the bat, the first couple of chunks that hit the writer are the same records. Reading through [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning) does not clarify enough about how the `Partitioner` is supposed to work. Are the dupes on multiple partitions supposed to happen? Perhaps a miss configuration on setting up the steps for partitioning? A simple example or a break down of how Partitioners actually work would be most helpful. Example of my setup below:

```
@Bean
public Job job(@Qualifier("step-one") @Autowired Step stepOne) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("my-first-spring-batch")
        .start(stepOne)
    .build();
}
```

```
@Bean(name = "PagingItemReader")
@StepScope
public JdbcPagingItemReader<Product> pagingItemReader(@Autowired PagingQueryProvider queryProvider) {
    return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<Product>().name("paging-reader")
        .dataSource(dataSource)
            .queryProvider(queryProvider)
                .rowMapper(new TheMapper())
        .pageSize(100)
            .maxItemCount(1000)
                .saveState(false)
    .build();
}
```

```
@Bean(name = "step-one")
public Step stepOne(@Qualifier("step-two") @Autowired Step stepTwo, @Autowired TaskExecutor taskExecutor, @Autowired SimplePartitioner partitioner) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step-one-partition")
        .partitioner("step-partition", partitioner)
            .gridSize(2)
                .step(stepTwo)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
    .build();
}
```

```
@Bean(name = "step-two")
public Step stepTwo(@Autowired JdbcPagingItemReader<Product> pagingItemReader) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step-two")
        .<Foo, Foo>chunk(10)
            .reader(pagingItemReader)
                .processor(itemProcessor)
            .writer(itemWriter)
    .build();
}
```

```
@Bean
public SimplePartitioner partitioner() {
    SimplePartitioner partitioner = new SimplePartitioner();
    partitioner.partition(10);

    return partitioner;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The partitioner is the piece that understands data and how to partition it. In your case, you are reading a db table so the partitioner should be implemented in a way to partition the table in a set of non-overlapping partitions, for example with IDs:

- Partition 1: 1..1000
- Partition 2: 1001..2000
- etc

This meta-data about partitions is then communicated to workers through `ExectuionContext` instances.

In your case, you use the `SimplePartitioner`, but this partitioner does not partition the table, it only creates "empty" execution contexts with numbered partition names as key. Hence, your workers will actually read the same data which explains the behaviour your are seeing.

A better example to look at is the [ColumnRangePartitioner](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/ColumnRangePartitioner.java#L36) and how to configure each reader from worker step to read from a given partition, see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/8762e3411557aaf887867f8d8594b01127538cb1/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/partitionJdbcJob.xml#L36-L60